# Where is the advantages of Repositories layer between controllers and models in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

there is a Repositories layer in my laravel project. I am a freshman about laravel. I can not fully understand the advantages of this layer. My colleagues tell me that it is purpose to lower the coupling of the codes. Obviously, it is true. But I also look forward to your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using repositories, we can create complicated query and isolated it behind a readable method name. The coupled used, when using eloquent, we must put the record name in eloquent query, but using repositories, we can hide the record name and put in the other place. So that is give some security reason too. Also we can use for grouped some entities for authoritative users. Repository allows abstraction from data provide engine.

[This](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/what-is-the-difference-between-a-model-and-a-repository) article can help you.